# How to access solidity function variables inside a transaction

Tags: solidity, ether, ethers.js, hardhat, chainlink

I am trying to assert that `address dogOwner` is equal to the deployer address in my unit tests,
but when I try to get the `dogOwner` variable from the `txReceipt` it returns: `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000f39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266` which is the deployer address with a bunch of numbers *(mostly 0's)* in front of it.
Am I getting the address of `dogOwner` incorrectly? Or is that just how the value is returned because of how solidity storage is arranged?

**Here is a screenshot of the test and the terminal output:**

[image]

**The functions related to the test:**

```
function requestNft() public payable returns (uint256 requestId) {
        if (msg.value < i_mintFee) {
            revert RandomIpfsNft__NeedMoreEthSent();
        }
        requestId = i_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(
            i_gasLane,
            i_subscriptionId,
            REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS,
            i_callbackGasLimit,
            NUM_WORDS
        );
        s_requestIdToSender[requestId] = msg.sender;
        emit NftRequested(requestId, msg.sender);
    }

    function fulfillRandomWords(uint256 requestId, uint256[] memory randomWords)
        internal
        override
    {
        address dogOwner = s_requestIdToSender[requestId];
        uint256 newTokenId = s_tokenCounter;
        // What does this token look like?

        uint256 moddedRng = randomWords[0] & MAX_CHANCE_VALUE;

        Breed dogBreed = getBreedFromModdedRng(moddedRng);

        _safeMint(dogOwner, newTokenId);
        _setTokenURI(newTokenId, s_dogTokenUris[uint256(dogBreed)]);
        emit NftMinted(dogBreed, dogOwner);
    }
```

Comment: Can you copy/paste the "mostly 0's" value in your question? Also, if it's possible, paste the whole contract.

Comment: @JeremyThen I think I realized my mistake: I am trying to look at the txReceipt of the VRFCoordinatorV2Mock's fulfillRandomWords tx, but I want to be looking at my contract's fulfillRandomWords txReceipt because that is where the dogOwner variable is.

Answer (score 1):

the address is just being padded to 32 bytes with zeros, and starting with a 0x

Comment: What about the 2?

Comment: The 2 it's just the index of the breed the `getBreedFromModdedRng(moddedRng)` function returned. Enums values are encoded by the index of where they are declared inside the enum. So a breed with index 2, it's the third enum value declared in the enum.

Answer (score 1):

What is the `Breed` type? A struct? A contract?

When I decode "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000f39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266" like:

```js
web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters(["uint256", "address"], "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000f39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266")
```

It returns:

```js
{
  "0":"2",
  "1":"0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266",
  "__length__":2
}
```

So, I'm wondering what that "2" might be. I decoded it treating the first part as a `uint256` and the second part as an `address`.

You could do that decoding and use it like:

```js
const decoded = web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters(["uint256", "address"], "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000f39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266");

console.log(deployer.address === decoded[1]);
```

Since you are emitting an event that has 2 parameters, the first being the enum Breed and the second the dog owner, then the first part of your encoded data it's the breed index, padded to 32 bytes: `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002`.
The second part is the address of the owner, padded to 32 bytes:
`000000000000000000000000f39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266`.

So, you just have to decode it and compare the second element with the address of the deployer.

Comment: Breed is an enum with 3 different dog breeds.

Comment: Yeah, that's why you have that '2' in there. Enums are encoded with the value being the index where they are declared.